# How do I index a CSV file which maps (mostly) consecutive integers to Strings so that I can search it efficiently in Java?

Tags: java, android, database, csv

I have a large CSV file (8000 rows) consisting of two columns. The first column is an integer ranging from 1 to 10000, and the second column is a string of 6 to 10 characters. Because my implementation is in Android, I am accessing the file using the AssetManager, so I must use an InputStream to read from the file.

The input into the system is an integer 1 through 10000, and the output is the corresponding string, or null if there was no integer match. A general use case of the app involves multiple (~4) such requests, each of which which under my current implementation freeze the app for 2-3 seconds.

I want to be able to do this search efficiently, using a phonebook (i.e., O(log(n)) time) search, without storing the entire file in memory. I assume that I should reformat the file from a CSV into something else... maybe a SQL database? What would an appropriate implementation be for this case?

I am entirely unfamiliar with large-scale data access, and to be honest my mental model of how and when files are loaded into memory and accessed on Android is a little fuzzy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend importing the csv file into a SqLite database. Here is a link on how to do just that: [SqLite3 CSV](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles) and here is an excellent tutorial on using SqLite with Android: [Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: How cool! Thank you so much for that link - it looks like exactly what I needed. Would the database then be packaged as a normal file into the Android assets folder?

Comment: this might be what you need: http://www.chriskopec.com/blog/2010/mar/13/deploying-android-apps-with-large-databases/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would. You can save it into internal memory or into your SD card. I also recommend you to migrate your data to SQLite. I've been checking on that link and looks really great.